# angular factory return data remained same after changing the json file

Tags: angularjs, json, service

i am calling a camera.json file from "cameraData" service and injecting the cameradata service in to "CameraController". If i change the camera.json after clicked on refresh button i am getting old data. Any idea?

.factory('cameraData', function ($http, $q,globalVariable) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

```
var cameraData = {};     
var contentType  = "application/json; charset=utf-8";   

cameraData.GetItemList = function(){ 
    $('.loader').show();
    var senddata ={};
    senddata.installedcameraid = "9547857793457943";
      $http({
        //url: globalVariable.ServerAddress + "Admin_GetCameraPoints",
        url: globalVariable.Camerafilepath,
        dataType: 'json',
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(senddata),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": contentType,
            "access_token": globalVariable.TOKEN
        }

    }).success(function(response){ 
        //$scope.response = response;
        deferred.resolve(response);
        return deferred.promise;

    }).error(function(error){
        //$scope.error = error;
        deferred.reject(error);
    });


    return deferred.promise;
}


return cameraData;
```

})

.controller('CameraController',function($scope,$timeout,cameraData){
    $scope.refreshCameraData = function(){

```
    $scope.allCamera = [];
    cameraData.GetItemList()
    .then(function(data) {
        $scope.allCamera = data.Camera;
    }, function(err) {
        // promise rejected, could log the error 
        console.log('error', err);
    });

}

cameraData.GetItemList()
    .then(function(data) {
        $scope.allCamera = data.Camera;
    }, function(err) {
        // promise rejected, could log the error 
        console.log('error', err);
    });
```

})

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you also format the first and last lines of code, as this may help people fast understanding the code, and thus be more in the offer an answer mood ;-) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create defer object everytime you call factory method. It should return new promise everytime you call api. Change your factory code with following.

```
var cameraData = {};
$('.loader').show();        
var contentType  = "application/json; charset=utf-8";   

cameraData.GetItemList = function(){
    // need to create defer object everytime 
    var deferred = $q.defer(); 
    $('.loader').show();
    var senddata ={};
    senddata.installedcameraid = "9547857793457943";
      $http({
        //url: globalVariable.ServerAddress + "Admin_GetCameraPoints",
        url: globalVariable.Camerafilepath,
        dataType: 'json',
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(senddata),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": contentType,
            "access_token": globalVariable.TOKEN
        }

    }).success(function(response){ 
        //$scope.response = response;
        $('.loader').hide();
        deferred.resolve(response);
        return deferred.promise;

    }).error(function(error){
        //$scope.error = error;
        $('.loader').hide();
        deferred.reject(error);
    });


    return deferred.promise;
}


return cameraData;
})
```

Comment: Succes is deprecated, use `.then`. Also, `$http` already returns a promise itself

Comment: That is all together different discussion.. :)

Comment: Different discussion or not, you shouldn't spread deprecated/wrong code

Comment: I was just correcting errors.. you are always welcome to share your version of code.. :)

Comment: thanks lot, yes i know success is deprecated, sorry about that.

Comment: i changed success to then, i already used in my controller :) anyway thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicitly create a deferred object and resolve/ reject it manually. the `$http()` method itself returns a promise and can be directly returned as below.

```
.factory('cameraData', function ($http, $q,globalVariable) {
    var cameraData = {};
    $('.loader').show();        
    var contentType  = "application/json; charset=utf-8"; 

    cameraData.GetItemList = function(){
        $('.loader').show();
        var senddata ={};
        senddata.installedcameraid = "9547857793457943";

        return $http({
            //url: globalVariable.ServerAddress + "Admin_GetCameraPoints",
            url: globalVariable.Camerafilepath,
            dataType: 'json',
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(senddata),
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": contentType,
                "access_token": globalVariable.TOKEN
            }

        }).then(function(response){ 
            $('.loader').hide();
        }).error(function(error){
            $('.loader').hide();
        });
    }

   return cameraData;
});
```

Also, for hiding the loader you can use the `.finally()` method as below:

```
        return $http({
            url: globalVariable.Camerafilepath,
            dataType: 'json',
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(senddata),
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": contentType,
                "access_token": globalVariable.TOKEN
            }

        }).finally(function(response){ 
            $('.loader').hide();
        });
```

In your controller, you can now access the response as,

```
.controller('CameraController',function($scope,$timeout,cameraData){

    $scope.refreshCameraData = function(){

        $scope.allCamera = [];

        cameraData
            .GetItemList()
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.allCamera = response.data.Camera;
            }, function(err) {
                // promise rejected, could log the error 
                console.log('error', err);
            });

    }


    cameraData.GetItemList()
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.allCamera = response.data.Camera;
        }, function(err) {
            // promise rejected, could log the error 
            console.log('error', err);
        });
    })
})
```

Comment: You can use `.finally` instead of both `.success` and `.error`, also `.success` and `.error` are deprecated

Comment: yes i can use .then , but my question was how to get the changed camera.json data from factory? any way thanks